# Swift retrieve User table custom columns

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I need to retrieve data from the User table working on the Parse. Default fields are available on PFUser (Ex email, username) but I need to get the custom columns (Ex age).

Where am I making a mistake?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

```
PFUser.currentUser()?["age"] as? int
```

for example

Comment: Thats work like my code, I try but don't get values.

Comment: I use it this way in my code and I get the information. for example:  let user = PFUser.current()!
                usuario = Usuario(nome: (user["nome"] as? String)!, email: (user["email"] as? String)!, cargo: (user["cargo"] as? String)!)
 Some fields in the user table are restricted and can only be retrieved by the owner user. Example, a logged in user cant obtain the email field from other users. In addition, the user must be logged in, so PFUser.current ()! Could you put a code example of is not working?